# Generate padding bytes for a structure by nesting it in a union

Tags: c, struct

I was going through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-structure-packing) to reaffirm my understanding of structure padding.I have a doubt now. When I do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ALIGNTHIS 16 //16,Not necessarily

union myunion
{
  struct mystruct
  {
    char a;
    int b;
  } myst;
  char DS4Alignment[ALIGNTHIS];
};

//Main Routine
int main(void)
{
  union myunion WannaPad;

  printf("Union's size: %d\n\
       Struct's size: %d\n", sizeof(WannaPad),
      sizeof(WannaPad.myst));

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Union's size: 16
Struct's size: 8
```

should I not expect the struct to have been padded by 8 bytes? If I explicitly pad eight bytes to the structure, the whole purpose of nesting it inside an union like this is nullified.

I feel that declaring a union containing a struct and a character array the size of the struct ought to be but isn't, makes way for a neater code.

Is there a work-around for making it work as I would like it?

Comment: What compiler and which options are used?

Comment: The union will be large enough to hold any of the inner types, but the inner types won't be padded to fit the other inner types.

Comment: "*[...] the size [of] the struct ought to be [padded]*" Why? For which sense/use? What would be the gain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> should I not expect the struct to have been padded by 8 bytes?

No, as the `struct mystruct` is seen/handled on its own. The `char` had been padded by <strike>3</strike> `sizeof (int) -1` bytes to let the `int` be properly aligned. This does not change, even if someone, somewhere, sometimes decides to use this very `struct mystruct` inside another type.

Comment: `sizeof(int)` is not fixed to 4.

Comment: @user4419802: Correct & Thanks! Fixed ... - :-)

Comment: "This does not change, even if someone, somewhere, sometimes decides to use this very struct mystruct inside another type." Aha!This is exactly what I was missing out on.

Answer (score 2):

Think about it logically.

Imagine I had a union with some basic types in it:

```
union my_union{
    int i;
    long l;
    double d;
    float f;
};
```

would you expect `sizeof(int) == sizeof(double)`?

The inner types will always be their size, but the union will always be large enough to hold any of its inner types.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it for primitive data types like the ones you've mentioned.  But when you consider a user-defined data-type like struct,a different logic  can actually be applied,which seems not to be the case. If I had declared the structure outside and defined an instance of it inside the union I wouldn't have got confused in the first place! Thank you,anyway :-)

Comment: @Adithya It makes no difference whether it is a primitive or structure within the union. That was just for illustration of your error in thinking. *any* type will be treated as it would outside of the `union`. No "different logic" can be applied.

Answer (score 1):

By default `struct` is padded, so `int b` field is aligned on `sizeof(int)` boundary. There are several workarounds for this:

- explicitly use fillers where needed: `char a; char _a[sizeof(int)-1]; int b;`
- use compiler-dependent pragma to pack `struct` on byte boundary
- use command-line switch etc.